# Having an array before encoding mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm trying to get a verification array to populate before mysql array in json_encode. this is the Array I would like before the mysql array "array("status":"true","message":"Data fetched successfully!","data":" But when I run the web service it just comes up blank.  Any ideas?

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","burtkunt_dbuser","phatelives","burtkunt_colors");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM colors";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode(array("status":"true","message":"Data fetched successfully!","data":$resultArray));
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is what I'd like it to look like:

```
{"status":"true","message":"Data fetched successfully!","data":[{"id":"1","name":"Roger Federer","country":"Switzerland","city":"Basel","imgURL":"https:\/\/demonuts.com\/Demonuts\/SampleImages\/roger.jpg"},{"id":"2","name":"Rafael Nadal","country":"Spain","city":"Madrid","imgURL":"https:\/\/demonuts.com\/Demonuts\/SampleImages\/nadal.jpg"},{"id":"3","name":"Novak Djokovic","country":"Serbia","city":"Monaco","imgURL":"https:\/\/demonuts.com\/Demonuts\/SampleImages\/djoko.jpg"},{"id":"4","name":"Andy Murray","country":"United Kingdom","city":"London","imgURL":"https:\/\/demonuts.com\/Demonuts\/SampleImages\/murray.jpg"},{"id":"5","name":"Maria Sharapova","country":"Russia","city":"Moscow","imgURL":"https:\/\/demonuts.com\/Demonuts\/SampleImages\/shara.jpg"},{"id":"6","name":"Caroline Wozniacki","country":"Denmark","city":"Odense","imgURL":"https:\/\/demonuts.com\/Demonuts\/SampleImages\/woz.jpg"},{"id":"7","name":"Eugenie Bouchard","country":"Canada","city":" Montreal","imgURL":"https:\/\/demonuts.com\/Demonuts\/SampleImages\/bou.png"},{"id":"8","name":"Ana Ivanovic","country":"Serbia","city":"Belgrade","imgURL":"https:\/\/demonuts.com\/Demonuts\/SampleImages\/iva.jpg"}]}
```

Comment: You have invalid php syntax.

Comment: (array("status":"true","message":"Data fetched successfully!","data":$resultArray) this isnt array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `array` is in incorrect format as

this is correct format

```
$array = array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");

$json_arr = array("status"=>"true","message"=>"Data fetched successfully!","data"=> $resultArray);

echo json_encode($json_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must select it first all value your database inside while like this

This my way to make json when select data from DB

```
$tempArray = array();

// Loop through each row in the result set
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{

    $data = array("id" => $row['id'], "name" => $row['name'],"country" => $row['country']);
    array_push($temparray, $data);
}
$arr= array("status"=>"true","message"=>"Data fetched successfully!", "data" => $temparray);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP array assignment is incorrect. Besides, I have found some other issue with your code. Here is an improved version

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","burtkunt_dbuser","phatelives","burtkunt_colors");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM colors";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    // $tempArray = array(); // unnecessary

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        // $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $row);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "true","message" => "Data fetched successfully!","data" => $resultArray));
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```